# Continuity of $f \cdot g$

Tags: real-analysis

We know that $f$ is continous everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$, $f \cdot g$ is also continous everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$, but $g$ is discontinous everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$. 
How to prove that the $f \equiv 0$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean, how to prove that $f$ is constant-valued?

Comment: @dshin this is not composition.

Comment: Suppose that $f(a)\neq 0$, Then there exists a neighberhood U containing $a$, such that $f\neq 0$ on U. Now you can get a contradiction (why?).

Comment: @hamed Should be an answer.

Comment: Sorry to give the answer late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to our claim, suppose that $f(a)\neq 0$. As $f$ is continous, it follows that there exists a neighberhood $U$ contaning $a$, such that $f\neq 0$ on $U$ (it suffices by considering $\epsilon = \frac{\vert f(a)\vert }{2}$). Now, $f$ and $f.g$ are continous on $U$, and $f\neq 0$ on $U$, therefore $g= \frac{fg}{f}$ should be continous on $U$ that is a contradiction.